# Fluent NHibernate and multiple key columns

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a User entity that has a IList property. The mapping for 
this looks like this:

```
        HasMany(x => x.Forms) 
            .Cascade.None() 
            .AsBag().KeyColumn("Supervisor") 
            .Key(key => key.Not.Update()) 
            .PropertyRef("Email");
```

Now I have a new feature request in that essentially adds another 
KeyColumn that should ALSO populate into this property. Essentially, 
each form can have a "Supervisor" and an "Alternate", and I need this 
property to populate any Forms where the `User.Email` is equal to either 
one (Forms BELONG to a User IF the `User.Email == Form.Supervisor OR User.Email == Form.Alternate`).

Is there a way to do this? Simply adding another `KeyColumn` 
specification simply overrides the previous one, and adding keys via 
the `Keys()` method seems to not allow for multiple key columns like I 
want... I'm looking for a way to essentially tell it that this 
relationship should be found with a `WHERE Superviser = Email OR Alternate = Email`, but it doesn't seem to support that `OR` clause...

My other option is essentially duplicate this mapping, but for "Alternate" in another property, and then slam the collections together in my consuming code, but I wanted to see if NHibernate was smart enough for this to be possible...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, no - NHibernate does not support this unusual type of join.  I would approach this exactly like you said.  Use two collections - `User.SupervisorForms` and `User.AlternateForms`, then combine them later, perhaps using LINQ's `Concat` method to do so.  You could define a property to do this concatenation for you:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<Form> Forms
{
    get { return SupervisorForms.Concat(AlternateForms); }
}
```

If you wish to load a `User` with a completely initialized `Forms` collection in a single round-trip to the database, then you can use this approach from the [Improving Performace - Multi Query](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#performance-multi-query) section of the NHibernate documentation:

```
User user = s.CreateMultiQuery()
    .Add("select u from User u left join fetch u.SupervisorForms where u.Id = :id")
    .Add("select u from User u left join fetch u.AlternateForms where u.Id = :id")
    .SetInt32("id", 123)
    .UniqueResult<User>();
```

This code uses `CreateMultiQuery()` and HQL - but the approach should work just as well with your choice of query batching syntax: `CreateMultiQuery()`, `CreateMultiCriteria()`, or `Future()` / `FutureValue()`.

Comment: This is exactly what I ended up doing, as my poking around the NHibernate base returned nothing. Goes against my desire to limit SQL hits as much as possible (this essentially doubles them), but it works and hasn't been a huge performance hit.

Comment: Added info about pre-loading those two collections in a single round-trip to the DB.  Note - NHForge appear to be down at the moment, so the link is broken, but Google has a [cached copy of the page](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:JC6X0f6JGfoJ:www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html+nhforge+documentation&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=firefox-a&source=www.google.com).